# Unable to build SQL queries dynamically in ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dynamic-sql

I am trying to generate SQL queries dynamically in an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework and C#.

I would like to generate a SQL query when a user selects a field (say Requester), operator (contains) and enters a parameter (say john) as shown in the following picture

[image]

To accomplish this I am using operators table in my database to frame the query.This is how my table looks like.

```
Operator       SqlCommand
---------------------------------------
  11           @field = '@param'
  12           @field <> '@param'
  13           @field LIKE '@param%'
  14           @field NOT LIKE '@param%'
  15           @field LIKE '%@param%'
  16           @field NOT LIKE '%@param%'
```

It is working fine when I use the hardcoded query,

```
var baseline_query = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<details>("Select requester,number,Title, Date, address from vwtest where requester LIKE '%john%'").ToList();
```

But when I tried to create it dynamically by passing parameters to where clause and Parameter using the following code.

**Note**: here `OperatorCode` for `Contains` is 15.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(String Field, int operator, String Parameter)
{
       var op = operator;
       var field = Field;
       var param = Parameter;
       res3 = db.Operators.Where(a => a.Operator == op).Select(a => a.SqlCommand).FirstOrDefault();

       using (var ctx = new DBEntities())
       {
           var new_query1 = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<details>("Select requester,number,Title, Date, address from vwtest where "+ res3, new SqlParameter("field", field), new SqlParameter("param", param)).ToList();
      }
}
```

It returns count = 0 in `new_query1` variable.

How do I create the above baseline query dynamically?

Comment: You can't put parameters inside single quotes. At the moment, it will be looking for the literal string '@param'. Remove the single quotes and try again

Comment: @GlynnHurrell No it didn't work.

Comment: plz include what res3 results in

Comment: my guess is you have to do the replacement before it hits ctx.Database.SqlQuery, as im guessing it wont allow you to set/modify fields... only values, it probably smart enough to know the diff... so you should do a string replace... before..